# How can I use randsample in Matlab without running out of memory?

Tags: matlab, random

I want to sample **without replacement** `m` integers between `1` and `n` in Matlab, where

```
m=10^6;
p=13^5;
n=p*(p-1)/2;
```

I have tried to use `randsample` as follows

```
random_indices_pairs=randsample(n,m);
```

However, I get a memory issue which is

```
    Error using zeros
    Requested 1x68929060278 (513.6GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays greater than this
    limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array size limit or preference panel for more
    information.

Error in randsample (line 149)
                x = zeros(1,n); % flags
```

Is there a way to avoid that? The issue here is due to the fact that `n` is huge.

Comment: One approach would be to randomly sample with replacement, then look for duplicates, and sample new values to replace those. This might only be reasonable if n >> m. The normal algorithm for sampling with replacement requires making an array with all the values to sample from.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I wrote based on your comment: 
`A=randi(n,m,1);`
`[U, I] = unique(A, 'stable');`
`A=A(I);`
`m_to_add=m-size(A,1);`

`while m_to_add>0`
      `B=randi(n,m_to_add,1);`
      `A=[A;B];`
      `[U, I] = unique(A, 'stable');`
      `A=A(I);`
      `m_to_add=m-size(A,1);`
`end`

Comment: Please post an answer with your code! It would be useful to future visitors. I would not repeat the `unique` (avoid code duplication!), but do `while true`, and then at the end of the loop `if m_to_add==0, break`. Also, `A=[A;B]` is very slow because it needs to copy all of `A`, it would be better to replace the non-unique elements in `A`. Not sure what the code for  that would look like though...

Comment: There's also the tiny problem that the array you're requesting is _abso-effing-lutely humongous_ (513.6GB). Are you sure your computer will have enough memory to allow loading > 500G of numbers into memory? Can it not be split into smaller operations that aren't so memory-intensive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two-input version of [`randperm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) is equivalent to `randsample` without replacement, and doesn't have memory issues:

```
random_indices_pairs = randperm(n, m);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below script should do what you're looking for.

- It first picks `m` random integers in the range `1` to `n`.
- Then it checks if there are any duplicate entries
- If not, the script stops
- If there are duplicate entries:

  - it goes through all of them
  - finds another random number between `1` and `n`
  - checks if that new random number exists in the array of integers

    - if it does, it finds another random number
    - if it doesn't, it replaces the duplicate in the array and moves on to the next duplicate

```matlab
%% Initialize
clearvars;
clc;

m = 10e6;
p = 13e5;
n = p*(p-1)/2;

%% Create m random integers between 1 and n
randomInt = randi(n, m, 1);

%% Find indices where duplicate random integers are
% Find indices of unique values, take the index of the first occurrence
[~, I] = unique(randomInt, 'first');
% Generate an array of all indices
dupIdx = 1:length(randomInt);
% Drop indices which point to the first occurrence of the duplicate
% This leaves indices that point to the duplicate
dupIdx(I) = [];
% Free up some memory
clear I;

if isempty(dupIdx)
    disp('Done!')
else
    % For those indices find another random number, not yet in randomInt
    disp('Found duplicates, finding new random numbers for those')
    counter = 0;
    for ii = dupIdx
        counter = counter + 1;
        disp(strcat("Resolving duplicate ", num2str(counter), "/", num2str(length(dupIdx))))
        dupe = true;
        % While the replacement is already in the randomInt array, keep
        % looking for a replacement
        while dupe
            replacement = randi(n, 1);
            if ~ismember(replacement, randomInt)
                % When replacement is unique in randomInt
                % Put replacement in the randomInt array at the right index
                randomInt(ii) = replacement;
                dupe = false;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on one of the comments (the comment suggests also possible improvements).

```
A=randi(n,m,1);
[U, I] = unique(A, 'stable');
A=A(I);
m_to_add=m-size(A,1);

while m_to_add>0
      B=randi(n,m_to_add,1);
      A=[A;B];
      [U, I] = unique(A, 'stable');
      A=A(I);
      m_to_add=m-size(A,1);
end
```

Comment: Glad you found a way! In case you need a bit more speed, the answer I posted is almost a second faster (even with the `disp` statements) :)